Cloudinary upload image
My code works locally, and I can upload images to Cloudinary. However, after deploying my code to the server, Cloudinary returns a 400 error even though the rest of the code works fine.
I believe the problem lies with Cloudinary. I have checked the server, and it functions correctly, sending requests to Cloudinary, which then returns a 400 error.
Everything works perfectly on my local setup, and I have verified that both the server and the code are functioning as expected.

i checked after turning of firewall
this code works in my local and i can upload image to cloudinary but it gives me 500 error in server after that i see 400 error in cloudinary:

Here is my code:
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadImage( List<IFormFile> image)
{
    IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
      .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
      .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
      .Build();

    string cloudName = configuration["Password:CloudName"];
    string apiKey = configuration["Password:ApiKey"];
    string apiSecret = configuration["Password:ApiSecret"];
    string cloudinaryFolder = "Home/Land";

    var cloudinaryAccount = new Account(cloudName, apiKey, apiSecret);
    var cloudinary = new Cloudinary(cloudinaryAccount);

    async Task<int> GetLastId()
    {
        var items = await RentHome.GetAll();

        if (items.Data.Any())
        {
            var lastItem = items.Data.FirstOrDefault();
            var RentHome = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Land>(lastItem);

            return RentHome.Id;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    var LastId = await GetLastId();

    if (image == null || image.Capacity == 0)
    {
        return BadRequest("No image provided");
    }

    try
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < image.Count; i++)
        {
            string uniqueFilename = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
            string cloudinaryImagePath = $"{cloudinaryFolder}/{uniqueFilename}";

            var uploadResult = UploadImageAndGetPath(cloudinary, image[i], cloudinaryImagePath);
            RentImgProcess.Add(new LandImg
            {
                ImgPath = cloudinaryImagePath,
                ImgIdForeignId = LastId,
            });

        }

        return Ok(new { Message = "Image uploaded successfully" });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return StatusCode(500, $"Internal server error: {ex.Message}");
    }
}

static string UploadImageAndGetPath(Cloudinary cloudinary, IFormFile image, string cloudinaryImagePath)
{
    using (var stream = image.OpenReadStream())
    {
        cloudinaryImagePath = cloudinaryImagePath.TrimStart('/');

        var uploadParams = new ImageUploadParams
        {
            File = new FileDescription(image.FileName, stream),
            PublicId = cloudinaryImagePath,
        };

        var uploadResult = cloudinary.Upload(uploadParams);

        return uploadResult.SecureUri.ToString();
    }
}


We probably need to see a [mcve], specifically code that reproduces the problem, to help you.  See [ask]: Help others reproduce the problem... if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some.  Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.  If you could please [edit] your question to share this, you're more likely to get useful answers here.


You tagged this [tag:c#] and [tag:reactjs], but the latter is a JavaScript library for building user interfaces.  Which language + framework are you using?  2) Is there any chance a firewall running on your server is blocking parts of your communication with Cloudinary?   3) Please [edit] your question to share the full raw raw 400 response from Cloudinary including any error messages.  Thanks!


Can you please log the full response you receive from Cloudinary when an HTTP 400 error is returned and share that?
